# BI publisher Bursting Issue

Tags: jdeveloper, bi-publisher, jdedwards

I am having an issue when running a report with BIP bursting.
Without bursting 1 pdf generated. Pdf displays 2 pages with page#1 and Page#2 that's fine.
but when bursting getting 2 output pdf. 2nd pdf page number is page#2. I want both page numbers to start from 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `@section` for each `for-each` section you want to have page numbering restart.

For example,

1. There are multiple orders in a delivery
2. There are multiple deliveries in a trip
3. You are printing against a trip
4. You need to restart numbering for each order

You would have:

```
<?for-each@section:trip/list_delivery/delivery?>
<?for-each@section:list_order/order?>
...insert content here, including page numbering...
<?end for-each?>
<?end for-each?>
```

I'm not certain this will work with bursting, but works with standard BI Publisher.